# Identify who did a checkout in SVN

Tags: apache, svn, logging, svn-checkout

In our SVN installation we have a requirement to identify who did the checkout of the repository and when.
Mostly its for audit purpose.

Is there any command to identify?
I checked in the Apache logs, but was not able to identify whether it was a checkout or not.

If there is any tool which can provide that information after parsing Apache logs - any inputs on that will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

SVN Book, Apache's configuration topic, [Apache logging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.logging) section

```
CustomLog logs/svn_logfile "%t %u %{SVN-ACTION}e" env=SVN-ACTION
```

in conf will generate, in common, more readable access-log with real Subversion operations, not DAV-commands

Answer (score 0):

You want to enable [high-level logging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.operational-logging.html) (i.e. operational log). 
Look for checkout or export events:

`checkout-or-export /path r62 depth=infinity`